# How to resolve conflicts between libraries/packages after null safety migration?

Tags: flutter, dart-null-safety

In the [firebase_auth](https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_auth) package, the User class has a property of photoURL defined as

```
  /// Returns a photo URL for the user.

  /// This property will be populated if the user has signed in or been linked
  /// with a 3rd party OAuth provider (such as Google).

  String? get photoURL {
    return _delegate.photoURL;
  }
```

where the string photoURL can be either populated or null.

In the [circular_profile_avatar](https://pub.dev/packages/circular_profile_avatar) package, the property [imageUrl](https://github.com/ch-muhammad-adil/flutter-plugin-circular_profile_avatar/blob/master/lib/circular_profile_avatar.dart) is defined as a non-null string.

```
/// it takes a URL of the profile image.
  final String imageUrl;
```

The problem I'm having is I need to pass the photoURL from the firebase_auth package to the circular_profile_avatar imageUrl, and at times the photoURL is null. Naturally, I'm getting the *String? cannot be assigned to String error message.* **How does Flutter recommend I resolve when parameters have different argument types within their respective packages?**

I have a widget, where currently imageUrl is throwing the error **The argument type 'String?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'String'** because natively CircularProfileAvatar accepts a String, but I need to have it be a String?, so I can pass photoURL to it from the firebase_auth package:

```
class CircleProfile extends StatelessWidget {
  @required final String? imageUrl;
  @required final double? radius;
  @required final double? elevation;
  @required final Widget? child;

  const CircleProfile({Key? key, this.imageUrl, this.radius, this.elevation, this.child}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return CircularProfileAvatar(
      //show current user photourl if exists, but if it does not exist, then give a null value
      imageUrl,
      radius: radius!,
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      borderWidth: 1, 
      borderColor: customGreen,
      elevation: elevation!,
      cacheImage: true,
      //if url is not null, show that as the placeholder
      placeHolder: (context,url) => Container(width: radius! - 2, height: radius! -2,child: CircularProgressIndicator()),
      child: child,
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: One way I'm thinking about fixing this, is handling photoURL before passing it to imageURL, checking if it is null, if it is null then assign it an empty string value. Will update here if that will suffice.